# Repeating on the same rule again and again in CFG-parser

Tags: parsing, compilation, racket, context-free-grammar, lalr

I have this rule :

```
 [<parameterList>
     [() (list 'parameterList)]
     [(<type> <varName> <ITERParamterList>) (append (list 'parameterList $1 $2) $3)]]
```

and if I add display I can see that it reacting for every option that possible - which means :
if I have
int a , int b , int c
it will try

```
() 
(a )
(a) (b)
(a) (b) (c)
```

so I am wondering why that happens (I guess because the implementation of the LALR(1) and is a must but : )  because in other similar rules, it doesn't happen!
how can I fix that ???